# DefaultGraphQLContext can not be cast to GraphQLServletContext

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, graphql-java

I have upgraded graphql version in my Springboot app. Below dependencies are added in build.gradle file

```
com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:14.1.0
com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:11.1.0
```

But when I am doing graphql calls now, I am getting below exception.

```
class graphql.kickstart.execution.context.DefaultGraphQLContext can not be cast to 
graphql.kickstart.servlet.context.GraphQLServletContext 
(graphql.kickstart.execution.context.DefaultGraphQLContext and 
graphql.kickstart.servlet.context.GraphQLServletContext are in unnamed module of loader 
org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWelappClassLoader
```

Comment: Did you get any resolution for this. Even i am facing this issue after upgrading from 12.0.0 to 14.1.0